# Property or Data Trigger in WPF Path object

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a TextBlock and two path objects (Up arrow & Down arrow) in a Stack Panel. The TextBlock is bound to a Property called 'Change', which possibly can have values such as -1,0,1.

**Problem**
I wanted to show Up arrow in case of 1 OR Down arrow in case of -1 OR show neither of these Path object in case of 0.

In order to achieve this, I defined a Style Trigger on Path type.

**Question**

I am not able to get it work. Am i missing something or is there better way of doing this.

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Name="changeLbl" Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding Path=Change}"/>
         <Path Fill="{Binding ElementName=changeLbl,Path=Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource downChangePathTrigger}"/>
                <Path Fill="{Binding ElementName=changeLbl,Path=Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource upChangePathTrigger}"/>
                </StackPanel>
```

**Style resource**

```
<Style x:Key="upChangePathTrigger" TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Data" Value="M 0 4 L 4 0 L 8 4 Z" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="GreenYellow"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Fill" Value="GreenYellow">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="downChangePathTrigger" TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Data" Value="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Fill" Value="Red">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

**Update with answer**

*Style trigger*

```
<Style x:Key="changePathTrigger" TargetType="Path">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Change,Converter={StaticResource doubleToIntConverter}}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="0"/>
                </DataTrigger>-->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Change,Converter={StaticResource doubleToIntConverter}}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Property="Data" Value="M 0 4 L 4 0 L 8 4 Z"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Change,Converter={StaticResource doubleToIntConverter}}" Value="-1">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    <Setter Property="Data" Value="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

*Xaml*

```
<Path Fill="{Binding ElementName=changeLbl,Path=Foreground}" Stroke="{Binding ElementName=changeLbl,Path=Foreground}" Style="{StaticResource changePathTrigger}"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a strange construction (trigger `Path.Visibility` with `Path.Fill` color which is bound to `TextBlock.Foreground`) but it will work with

```
<TextBlock Name="changeLbl" Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding Path=Change}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="GreenYellow" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="-1">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

But I think you should reduce the dependencies e.g. replace `Trigger` in path style with a `DataTrigger` to depend from property 'Change' directly. Then for example you can change your `Path` or `TextBlock` colors and `Visibility` is still working.

```
<Style x:Key="upChangePathTrigger" TargetType="Path">
    ...
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Change}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Sorry for the naive approach since I am newbie. Now, can you suggest me how to switch between different path object or hiding both completely based on the property Change ?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Your code snippet is all about to set the visibility / Foreground of TextBlock based on the Property. But my concern is, given two path object,  how to switch between different path object or hiding both completely based on the property Change.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. My second code snippet is a sample for Up arrow style. Same you need for Down arrow style with Value="-1". Then Visibility of each path object is bound to property Change.

Comment: Thanks for correcting it. So the point is, We have to use DataTrigger when we need some changes in properties based on dynamic data.